# Multi-threaded task queue with shutdown in Twisted

Tags: python, concurrency, twisted

I'm trying to get into writing multi-threaded scripts in Python for processing large lists of files. In the past, I've used utilities like GNU Parallel, but my needs are starting to exceed what that program can provide.

I've written a simple demo in Java which demonstrates what I'd like to do here:

```java
public class ExecutorTest {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorTest t = new ExecutorTest();
        t.start();
    }

    public ExecutorTest() {

    }

    public void start() {
        File f = new File(".");

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            final String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            this.executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
//                  sleep for up to 100 milliseconds
                    try { Thread.sleep(new Double(Math.random() * 100.0).longValue()); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                    System.out.println(fullPath);
                }
            });
        }

        this.executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            this.executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do the same thing in Twisted but I'm having a difficult time understanding how all the working pieces come together so I can start a bounded multi-threaded worker queue, then wait for it to finish.

How do you write something like this in Twisted? I've done a lot of work in Python so I'm not learning Python, I'm just trying to figure out how to use Twisted.

Comment: Is Twisted a real requirement? Why not use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/threadpool?

Comment: Twisted is not a real requirement, though I'd like to use "actual" threads if at all possible, and I'm not interested in "multiprocessing." I'll look into threadpool and see if it addresses my requirements.

Comment: Also, [from threadpool's project website](http://chrisarndt.de/projects/threadpool/): "This module is regarded as an extended example, not as a finished product. Feel free to adapt it too your needs."

Comment: Why not multiprocessing? It is how serious work is done on python :D and there is always the [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) for use with threading.

Comment: It's a requirement to not spawn multiple processes: one process with many threads.